# parallel with snowfall - local vs remote speed

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow, snowfall

I am using `snowfall` for parallel processing on my desktop machine without any problems. I want to use several spare machines in the office to increase speed of the computations and want to distribute the parallel processing over the remote machines.

I have it working, but am experiencing an issue where distributing over the remote is **much** slower than either just running locally, or by running the code manually (i.e locally) on the other (remote) machine.

My tests show that the parallel processing over the remote cluster is about 14 times slower than running locally. I realize that there will be some overhead with distributing over the network, but thought it wouldn't be this inefficient.

### Example Speed Test

```
testFun <- function(i, n=1E4) rnorm(n)
nsim <- 2000
```

#### Local machine -  without parallel processing

```
st <- Sys.time()
temp <- sapply(1:nsim, testFun)
Sys.time() - st
# about 1.5 seconds
```

#### Local machine  - with parallel processing

```
library(snowfall)
snowfall::sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 8)
st <- Sys.time()
temp <- snowfall::sfSapply(1:nsim, testFun)
Sys.time() - st

# snowfall 1.84-6.1 initialized (using snow 0.4-2): parallel execution on 8 CPUs.
# Time difference of ~0.9 secs
```

#### Remote machine - run directly on remote machine

```
testFun <- function(i, n=1E4) rnorm(n)
nsim <- 2000

library(snowfall)
snowfall::sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 8)
st <- Sys.time()
temp  <- snowfall::sfSapply(1:nsim, testFun)
Sys.time() - st
# snowfall 1.84-6.1 initialized (using snow 0.4-2): parallel execution on 8 CPUs.
# Time difference of ~ 1 sec
```

#### Local machine - distributed to remote

```
remote <- list(host = "14*.***.***.***", 
                  rscript = "Rscript", 
                  snowlib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library",
                  rshcmd = "plink.exe -pw *********",
                  user="******",
                  master = '14*.***.***.***')

sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 8, type = "SOCK", 
       socketHosts = list(remote,remote,remote,remote, 
                          remote, remote, remote, remote))

st <- Sys.time()
tt <- snowfall::sfSapply(1:nsim, testFun)
Sys.time() - st
# snowfall 1.84-6.1 initialized (using snow 0.4-2): parallel execution on 8 CPUs.
# Time difference of ~ 14 secs
```

My function is obviously more computationally intensive than this, and has multiple calls to `sfSapply`. I notice about the same increase in run time when distributing to the remote machine - about 12 - 15 times longer than when run directly in R on remote machine.

#### Questions

Am I doing something stupid? Is there a better way to do this?

Or is this due to the network communication between the local and remote machines and unavoidable?

Local machine: Windows 10; R 3.4.3
Remote machine: Ubuntu 17.10; R 3.4.3

Comment: Parallel evaluation is most helpful when the computational tasks are large and data transfer small -- try a test function that takes a long time but involves little data transfer, e.g., `testFun = function(i) Sys.sleep(5)` --

Comment: The test with little data transfer took the same amount of time. This suggests my issue is the large amount of data I'm passing for each call to `sfSapply`. My function involves both large computations and data transfer. I'll look into ways to reduce the data transfer if possible.